# @aws/cdk cfnfunction upload code python structure

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use `CfnFunction` to crate lambda but everything works as expected except the uploading `code` using

```
code_ = lambda_.CfnFunction.CodeProperty(
                           zip_file = "./function-code/db-snapshot/index.py")
    or 
                           zip_file = "./function-code/db-snapshot/index.zip")
```

after using this my lambda just creates only `index.py` and the context of the file is the path

`./function-code/db-snapshot/index.py` like this

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

If you upload index.py and index.py is on AWS, what is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cfn methods are escape hatches for when the CDK Construct does not have the necessary properties that you are trying to access from CloudFormation  yet.

Lambda, however, is pretty much a done deal in CDK - you should be using aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function() for creating a [cdk lambda resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/README.html) (see link for docs)

Then from there you can use the `aws_lambda.AssetCode()` methods to retrieve your code and zip it up for you

```
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda

aws_lambda.Function(self, "MyLambda",
    runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    handler="index.handler",    
    code=aws_lambda.AssetCode(os.path.join("path to your lambda directory", "index.py"))
  )
```

the above snippet assumes your have a file called index.py, and inside that file is a method defined as `def handler(event, context):` that is the entry point for your lambda.

Comment: Then it's a best practice to use L2 constructs (like `Function` )instead of `cfn`?. Thank you so much for the explanation, forund one more way to do that through `Function`

` with open(config.lambdafn.code_path, encoding="utf-8") as fp:
            on_event_code_body = fp.read()`
`code=lambda_.InlineCode(on_event_code_body)`

Comment: yes - it is. The Cfn constructs are left around from the early implimentations of cdk, and only remain for the few things that haven't been implimented yet. The higher level functionalities have hooks into all the interface parts to allow them to hook together. For instance with `aws_lambda.Function` you can call  `aws_lambda.Function().Role` and access the auto generated role and add policies to it. As a child of `iFunction` it also slots right into any other Construct that needs a function arn/name for one of its properties. -- If the answer was helpful, please mark it as so!

Comment: I was started using the L2 constructs it gives wide flexibility, and thank you so much for the help, really apriciated